# SQL : UPDATE a table from another table

Tags: sql

I want to update table Y, with information from table X, just once.

So, after this query:

```
UPDATE y
SET y.Salary = x.salary
FROM x, y
WHERE x.ID_FK = y.ID 
  AND end >= (SELECT MAX(end) FROM x WHERE end >= '10-10-2005')
```

I get this:

table y

```
ID SALARY    
----------
1   1000    
2   1500    
3   2000
```

instead of this:

```
ID    SALARY    
-------------
1      2000    
2       700    
3       350
```

Here are the tables:

[image]

In conclusion, I want to write a query who can update TABLE Y using the last field for each ID from table X. Take only the last information inserted.

How could I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and there is no way to join tables in an UPDATE statement in standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE y
set y.Salary = x.salary
from x, y
where x.ID_FK = y.ID 
  and end >= (select max(t.end) 
              from x as t
              where t.end >= '10-10-2005'
                and t.ID_FK = x.ID_FK)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you a lot.

Comment: Could you explain to me the purpose of "t" ? I try to figure out how work the second part of the query. From ">=" to the final query i cant understand.

Comment: That is becasue you have a table `x` in the outside and you also need a table `x` in the subquery. So you create an alias `t` to difference between both